# Java applets and Windows 7 screen DPI setting

Tags: java, screen-resolution, dpi

I am running Windows 7 and have set the screen DPI setting to a higher value because otherwise text and icons are too small to read on my 1080p monitor. Most programs also can be configured to either adhere to or ignore this setting on an individual basis if needed.

Unfortunately, I am unable to change the DPI for certain (all?) Java programs, such as this one:

http://www.geogebra.org/cms/en/

The program always ignores my screen DPI setting; so the application, fonts, lines, curves, etc. are nearly too small and skinny to be visible. (However, when embedded inside a Web page the applet follows the settings of the browser, and appears OK.)

Anyone know how to fix this problem on my computer or in the program's source code?

Comment: How else do you need to start the applet other than through Web browser?

Comment: The program can also be installed like a regular application, including icons in the Start menu and on the Desktop.

Comment: It's something you should take up with the programmers.

Comment: I need to approach the developers with something a little more substantial. The last suggestion I got on the forums was to change my desktop resolution. :|